# How can I republish an app that has been removed from Google play

Tags: android, google-play

Three years ago I published a React Native App in Google Play Store using React Native / Expo. The app has been functioning well but unfortunately it used REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. For that reason Google removed the App from Google Play.

I refactored the app to the newest version of Expo and rebuilt the app without using the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. I have tried in many ways to create a new release but I am not able to send it for review. It's driving me nuts.

Whatever I do, I keep getting this warning: 'You can't submit updates as some information about your app is incomplete' Underneath is a button that leads me to 'App Content'

Following the link to App Content then asks me to declare why my app needs the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. This however does not apply to the new release as this does not require the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. For the old version however, I have no valid reason to use the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

Anyone knows what to do? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to contact support?

Comment: I think you might have missed some sections like data safety, app policy, etc just check everything once again